# How are Thin Slice Beef rolls for hot-pot prepared in restaurants?

Tags: beef

I was wondering how Thin Slice Beef rolls for hot-pot prepared for in hot-pot restaurants. Are they sliced and manually rolled, or is there a machine that is used to do the lot? Cheers.
Picture for reference: https://chowtimes.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/hot-pot-at-chez-suanne-7.jpg

Answer (score 4):

When I worked at a Japanese restaurant in Seattle years ago they would freeze the beef and then use a meat slicer to cut it really thin, then roll it up. It's possible there is a newer device i'm unaware of that does it automatically but it is a fairly simple process.

Comment: They would *partially* freeze it, right? As in not solidly frozen?